# Framework not found MDFInternationalization for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, frameworks, admob, xcode9.1

I am trying to integrate Googleadsmeditationsuite in the iOS project. I have installed sdk using Pod and when I try to build a project then I get below error

> ld: framework not found MDFInternationalization for architecture x86_64

I have tried everything I can but not able to get rid of this error.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @stanimirsp Did you find a solution? I am also having the same problem at this time.

Comment: @MubinMall, yes but I can't remember it right now it's been a while. Did you tried this [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660864)

Comment: Okay Thanks! Will try that!